# axios onUploadProgress not call

Tags: reactjs, firefox, axios

I have react project and use this code in it:

```
 let data = new FormData();
 data.append('img', file, 'image.jpg');
 axios.post('/upload', data, {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
        },
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
            setProgress(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total));
        }
    })
```

Code works perfectly on development but when react build on production server `onUploadProgress` never called on firefox and android chrome but again it perfectly works on mac osx chrome

**Update**:
I remember it works on chrome but I test it again it doesn't work.
Now code only works in development

Comment: what error message do you get? try append the catch block and log the error `.catch((error) => {
    if( error.response ){
        console.log(error.response.data); // => the response payload 
    }
});`

Comment: That sounds like CORS error. Try to turn off corsDomain config.

Comment: @MWO I don't have any error and image uploaded without problem only `onUploadProgress` not work

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue on React Native.